# How to write extension methods for both Nullable and Not Nullable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, extension-methods, nullable

I've written the following Extension Method

```
    <Extension()>
    Public Function ToUtcIso8601(ByVal dt As Date) As String
        Return String.Format("{0:s}Z", dt)
    End Function
```

But I also need a Nullable version of the same method... how exactly do I do this?

This is what I was thinking, but I'm not sure if this is the right way

```
    <Extension()>
    Public Function ToUtcIso8601(ByVal dt As Date?) As String
        Return If(dt, Nothing).ToUtcIso8601()
    End Function
```

or another option

```
    <Extension()>
    Public Function ToUtcIso8601(ByVal dt As Date?) As String
        Return If(Not dt Is Nothing, ToUtcIso8601(dt), Nothing)
    End Function
```

I'm just not sure the "right" way to do this.

## Edited

This actually works, But...

```
    Public Function ToUtcIso8601(ByVal dt As Date?) As String
        Return If(Not dt Is Nothing, ToUtcIso8601(dt.Value), Nothing)
    End Function
```

Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [extension method on type and nullable<type>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742336/extension-method-on-type-and-nullabletype)

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim yeah it is and it isn't. This one is visual basic, the other is c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for the second option.  Unfortunately, when using extension methods on a Date struct, Date? extension methods are not applicable, otherwise you could just declare one extension for the Date? type.  You will have to take a similar approach to the one you already have in order to support both types.

Comment: unfortunately my second option keeps crashing the WebDev service

Comment: You'll need to supply a stack trace or something then.

Comment: Shouldn't the line read: `Return If(Not dt Is Nothing, ToUtcIso8601(dt.value), Nothing)`

Comment: debugger looks like it's creating an infinite loop

Comment: Ah yes, David is right. I wasn't sure if VB automatically extracted nullable values, but that's actually not even relevant here.  You are recursing into the method over and over by not using dt.Value -- you are supplying a Date?, and that's causing the infinite recursion.

Comment: I added the .Value to no avail

Comment: Then something else is wrong. Make sure that the service was restarted if necessary and look for another stack trace.

Comment: ok, I got it. Turns out I was calling it incorrectly in the initial call.  I was using `ToUtcIso8601(dt)` instead of `dt.ToUtcIso8601()`

Comment: i'm still wondering if I'm doing it right, or just "doing it".

Comment: @rockinthesixstring: This looks good to me, however I've always found the .HasValue property of a nullable type cleaner to use in these sorts of situations; I would use something like:

Return If(dt.HasValue, ToUtcIso8601(dt.Value), Nothing)