# Extension method resolution with nullable value type params

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, overloading, extension-methods

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static void Test(this DateTime? dt)
    {
    }
}


void Main()
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    Extension.Test(now); // ok
    now.Test(); // compile time error
}
```

I'm just curious, why is the compiler not able to resolve the same method when called as an extension?

Comment: Just see the error, your curiosity will be gone.

Comment: I was about to ask this very question, wondering if it was a compiler bug. Does the C# language have a place to file bug reports?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [extension method on type and nullable<type>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742336/extension-method-on-type-and-nullabletype)

Answer (score 3):

A `DateTime` is [not convertible to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986458%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `Nullable<DateTime>` explicitly.

The C# specification, 7.6.5.2 Extension method invocations:

An extension method is eligible if:

- Mj is accessible and applicable when applied to the arguments as a static method as shown above
- An implicit identity, reference or boxing conversion exists from expr to the type of the first parameter of Mj.

...

If no candidate set is found in any enclosing namespace declaration or compilation unit, a compile-time error occurs.

So you have to cast the `DateTime` to `Nullable<DateTime>` explicitly or use a nullable from the beginning:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
((DateTime?)now).Test();
```

or

```
DateTime? now = DateTime.Now;
now.Test();
```

Comment: That link says it *is* implicitly convertible. And if it wasn't then the standard static method call would also fail. Unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet: maybe i I did not express myself well

Comment: I still don't see which of the eligibility requirements you quote from the spec are not met. The method is visible/applicable as a static method and an implicit conversion exists.

Comment: Lets revive this topic for a moment... the critical point is, a value type -> nullable conversion is an implicit conversion, but it is *not a boxing conversion*. This is why the second bullet point in the list doesn't apply, even though it reads as if it should apply.

Answer (score 1):

As Tim said nullable +1

Fix:

```
  public static class Extension
  {
    public static void Test(this DateTime? dt)
    {
    }
  }

  public class Program
  {
    private void Main()
    {
      DateTime? now = DateTime.Now;
      Extension.Test(now); 
      now.Test();  
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`var` isn't a type. The actual type is figured out at compile-time. If you set `DateTime.Now` for a `var`, it will recognize as a `DateTime` type, not a `Nullable<DateTime>`, and that's why it doesn't compile.

`var` variables are also known as [Implicitly Typed Local Variables (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)

By the way, you can also create a generic extension method for nullable types:

```
public static T? GenericMethod<T>(this T? source) where T : struct
{
    //Do something
}
```

and you can call whatever is nullable, declaring its type:

```
DateTime? dateTimeNullable = DateTime.Now;
dateTimeNullable.GenericMethod();

int? intNullable = 0;
intNullable.GenericMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you wrote an extension for `DateTime?` and not for `DateTime`.

```
        DateTime? now = DateTime.Now;
        Extension.Test(now); // ok
        now.Test(); // no compile time error
```

or

```
        var now = new DateTime?(DateTime.Now);
        Extension.Test(now); // ok
        now.Test(); // no compile time error
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create your variable now with the corret type nullable like this:

```
 DateTime? dateTime = DateTime.Now;
 dateTime.Test();
```